Formulas for the number of spanning subgraphs of a certain type.
A spanning subgraph of a finite graph $G = (V,E)$ is a graph $(V,F)$ where $F \subset E$.
That is one keeps all the vertices and some of the edges.
Any graph $G=(V,E)$ has $2^{\vert E \vert}$ spanning subgraphs.
Now, and even graph is a graph where all vertices have even degree. It turns out that a graph $(V,E)$ with $\kappa$ components has $2^{\vert E \vert - \vert V \vert + \kappa}$ spanning even subgraphs.
Are there other graph properties where the number of subgraphs with that property have similar simple formulas?
For example, the matrix tree theorem could be one example of such a simple formula, but maybe it is a bit too complicated.
Other examples of properties could be: Triangle-free, d-regular, forest, spanning tree, bipartite, Eulerian paths, etc. But for most of those cases counting the number is NP-hard and thus there is no nice formula.

You mention the elegant the matrix tree theorem, which states the number of spanning trees of a graph is equal to any cofactor of its Laplacian. The BEST theorem (after de Bruijn, Ehrenfest, Smith, and Tutte) states that the number of Eulerian circuits in a digraph $D = (V, A)$ is
$$
t(D)\prod_{v\in V}(\deg^{-}(v)-1)!
$$
where $t(G)$ is the number of arborescences, and can be computed via a version of the matrix tree theorem (see Wikipedia). That such a theorem exists is somewhat interesting, because counting Eulerian circuits in undirected graphs is #P-complete.
You might also be interested in the Tutte polynomial, but here you do encounter computational complexity issues.
